# printing sequential numbers in a preset position

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a simple program that will print page numbers sequentially between two set numbers, in a specified position, say bottom right or top center. I have tried all the ways that I can think of but the program will only write to the file if I set the first page to print at a higher value than the last. Even then only one number is filed. here is the coding so far. Some help will be much appreciated. As it is over 30 years since I last wrote programs I am more than a bit rusty.

```
ECHO OFF
REM  To print sequential numbers at a specified point on pages i.e. bottom right or top center. starting
REM from a given number (a) and ending with the second given number (b)
CLS
ECHO Enter the number of the first page to print
SET  /P a=[promptString                          ]
ECHO Enter  the number of the last page to print
SET /P b=[promptString                           ]
REM  requires coding to identify the position to print ie bottom right or top center
CLS
ECHO
ECHO
ECHO
ECHO                        Printing from page number   
ECHO                                  %a%
ECHO                             to page number 
ECHO                                  %b%
PAUSE
:L
ECHO %a%> test.txt
REM send value of a to file text.txt to print 
REM requires coding to print each page from text.txt ejecting each page after printing
SET /a a=(%a+1)
REM Increments value of a to next page value then returns to file and print new value of a 
IF %a% GTR %b% GOTO X
REM Stops printing at last page (value b)
GOTO L
:X
EXIT
```

Comment: `SET /a a=(%a+1)` is wrong. Use `SET /a a=(%a%+1)` or `SET /a a=(a+1)` or `SET /a a+=1`

Answer (score 0):

Just repeating the correct answer from the comments, so it gets shown as answered!

```
SET /a a=(%a+1)
```

Should be

```
SET /a a += 1
```